# How to create a seperate blog page on my site with a different theme

Tags: wordpress, blog, theme

My website is currently setup as a blog, where there are categories and post within them. However I want to create a separate page where I can discuss news, ideas, and thoughts, while having a different theme.

Comment: Richard, do you have more information such as blog software you are using? As well, I understand what you are seeking, but this is too open ended in my book. Do you have a more specific question? Can you narrow this down and add some information so someone can help you? Otherwise, we would be guessing and offering opinions.

Comment: Hi closetnoc, I am currently using Wordpress. My site consist of categories and post that are relevant to those categories. I want to add a separate page where I can discuss news, information, and random thoughts that pertain to the topic of my site. I was going to add it on a subdomain, but apparently that is not good SEO practice. So I am opting to create a subfolder for my blog. However, I want to know if I can create a new theme for this subfolder? In short: Create a blog subfolder, blog has different theme than main site.

Comment: So you can create pages in Wordpress and make it use a different template... If you're unsure how to do that, I'd suggest checking in over at [Wordpress SE](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Perfect! Unfortunately, I know nothing about WordPress. But your explanation is perfect. I am sure someone will be able to help.

Comment: Often the themes offer various design options, that the admin can use. The other option is to use plugins such as https://wordpress.org/plugins/dx-template-manager/screenshots/